# Add new item to list before initializing or after?

Tags: c#

Which do you prefer?

```
var foo = new Foo();

foo.Prop1 = "1";
foo.Prop2 = "2";
// etc...

this.Foos.Add(foo);
```

or

```
var foo = new Foo();
this.Foos.Add(foo);

foo.Prop1 = "1";
foo.Prop2 = "2";
// etc...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of this is personal preference vs. concrete reasons but I prefer first because I find it to be the more straight forward approach.  It follows the way I would think about this problem.  It simply seems backwards to add it to the list and then initialize the value.

The one concrete reason I would prefer the first is it's more resilient to changes in your code.  For example if `Foo` was later changed from a class to a struct it would break scenario #2 but not #1.  This is a pretty far corner case though.

In C# 3 and higher you could also simplify this by using a collection initializer.

```
this.Foos.Add(new Foo() { Prop1="1"; Prop2="2" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the first variation.  It is logically sound and easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to initialize properties with: (C# 3 or later)

```
this.Foos.Add(new Foo() { Prop1 = 1, Propr2 = 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first simply because it seems cleaner to completely initialize the object before you are "done" with it.  Also before you pass an object off to a method that may have side effects on the object itself it is best to ensure that you have properly initialized it in order to avoid any `InvalidOperationExceptions`.  You never know if the `Add` method expects  `foo.Prop1` to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In doing WinForm or ASP.Net, I would choose First approach, although no difference in terms of performance. I do this because it seems like I initialize everything and put the object to its place, rather than I put something there and alter it again and again. Just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

The first, because:

- it keeps the code that is logically
  coupled closer (all the code setting
  properties, attributes, and overall
  working on foo closer together than
  the code where foo is treated as a 
  unit in a larger context which is the
  collection of all foos);
- you never know if adding a Foo to the
  collection of foos may add a deep
  copy (rather than a shallow
  reference) so, assuming the intent is
  to have all those properties set on
  the instance in the collection, I
  always set the properties before
  passing foo to any method that may or
  may not create an alias for it

Answer (score 0):

An old thread....

What about when you are searching for an item, creating a new item if not found, and changing it if found?

e.g.

```
var item=foos.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Prop1=="1");
if (item==default)
{
   item=new Foo();
   foos.Add(item);
}

item.Prop2="2";
```